# ogr2ogr sql: what is the name of the geometry field?

Tags: ogr2ogr, ogrinfo

I have the following `ogrinfo -so` output about a shapefile:

```
Layer name: PREDEFINED
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 58075
Extent: (425995.430000, 336399.500000) - (447356.663000, 359782.760000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["OSGB 1936 / British National Grid",
    GEOGCS["OSGB 1936",
        DATUM["OSGB_1936",
            SPHEROID["Airy 1830",6377563.396,299.3249646,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7001"]],
            TOWGS84[446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6277"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
        AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4277"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","27700"]]
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
LABEL: Integer (0.0)
```

I want to run an `ogr2ogr` SQL query to get back just the `gml_id` and the spatial field as WKT. This is what I'm trying:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.gml -sql "select gml_id, geom from PREDEFINED"
```

But I get `ERROR 1: Unrecognized field name geom.`.

How can I work out what the geometry field name is? I can't see it in the ogrinfo output - is it a standard name?

Comment: should be `GEOMETRY`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing `geom` to `Geometry` should solve the issue. However, I also get the same error after this change. You should also add the `-dialect sqlite` option (I've tested with another dataset on my computer)

Running the following solve the issue

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON output.geojson input.gml -dialect sqlite -sql "select gml_id, Geometry from PREDEFINED"
```

FIY, you may want to look at the [gdal-cheat-sheet github repository](https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet) that give a bunch of recipes to better use gdal/ogr.

PS: you can also use `OGR_Geometry` instead of `Geometry` if you don't want/need to use `-dialect sqlite` option (credit to @user30184 answer I upvoted)

Comment: +1 for the inclusion of `-dialect sqlite`. I usually include this setting, and when I've messed something up it's usually because I've forgotten this flag.

Answer (score 7):

One possibility is to check the documentation
https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html

> Geometry field
>
> The GEOMETRY special field represents the geometry of the feature
>   returned by OGRFeature::GetGeometryRef(). It can be explicitly
>   specified in the result column list of a SELECT, and is automatically
>   selected if the wildcard is used.
>
> For OGR layers that have a non-empty geometry column name (generally
>   for RDBMS datasources), as returned by OGRLayer::GetGeometryColumn(),
>   the name of the geometry special field in the SQL statement will be
>   the name of the geometry column of the underlying OGR layer.

https://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql.html

> OGR_GEOMETRY
>
> Some of the data sources (like MapInfo tab) can handle geometries of
>   different types within the same layer. The OGR_GEOMETRY special field
>   represents the geometry type returned by
>   OGRGeometry::getGeometryName() and can be used to distinguish the
>   various types. By using this field one can select particular types of
>   the geometries like:

Or then you can make a try with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo -sql "select * from test" test.shp
INFO: Open of `test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: test
Geometry: 3D Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (327.000000, 228.000000) - (630.000000, 631.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = _ogr_geometry_
OGRFeature(test):0
  POLYGON Z ((327 497 20,447 631 20,630 498 20,381 228 20,327 497 20))


ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from test" test.shp
INFO: Open of `test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: 3D Polygon
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (327.000000, 228.000000) - (630.000000, 631.000000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
Geometry Column = GEOMETRY
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  POLYGON Z ((327 497 20,447 631 20,630 498 20,381 228 20,327 497 20))
```

So the name of the geometry is "OGR_GEOMETRY" for the OGR SQL and either "GEOMETRY" or the real name that is used in the datasource for the SQLite SQL dialect.

Comment: I used `ogr2ogr` `spat` on CORINE Land Cover with `shp` output, and `ogrinfo` doesn't return any info about geometry column. It is not `"geometry"`, it is not `"ogr_geometry"` it is not `"geom"` and it is not `"shape"` ... so what is it??? how do I find it? I was able to return the geometry for CORINE geopackage with `PRAGMA table_info(table_name);` command, but that doesn't work on `shp`

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to read the documentation, which is now here: https://gdal.org/user/ogr_sql_dialect.html

In my case, the source layer had format GeoPackage, and here [https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html] one can find that the geometry column for GeoPackage is named `geom`.

So to add `SELECT …, geom FROM geoPkgLayer` did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try leaving out any reference to geometry in the `-sql` flag. For example, converting a GZ to a GeoPackage while selecting 2 non-spatial fields, I use this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "GPKG" output.gpkg input.gz "LayerName" -sql "SELECT column1, column2 FROM LayerName"
```

Note- no reference to `geom` or `Geometry` required and the output dataset still has geometry data when loading into QGIS.